# Getting data from SQLite in fragment in 1s interval until 5s

Tags: android, fragment, runnable

In onCreateView method of my fragment, I want to get some data from device SQLite in 1s interval. Once got, show it. If can't get in 5s, then show "not available".

Tried runnable thread, but not working, the runnable was not called. Some codes as below.

**Any good suggestions on how to fix it or other better solutions?** Much appreciated!

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int timer = 0;

handler.postDelayed(getData, 1000);

final Runnable getData = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        DataHandler optionHandler = new TripDataHandler(mContext);
        ArrayList<Entity> data = dataHandler.getData();

        if(timer >= 5){
             handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }

        if(data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

        timer++;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to fetch data between the interval of 1 to 5.Is there any specific reason to do this,wht is your exact requirement ?what do u want exactly ? can u elaborate me?

Comment: Activity(A) fetches lots of data for 5 types, then store in SQLite and display them on the next activity(B), the performance is bad. 
So, we changed code to fetch 2 of 5 types data and show first. Then user can click "see more" to activity C (where the fragment included) which has 5 tabs, clicking any one of them, show data of one type. 
When user click one tab, data might be not ready, I wanna fetch 5 times to check if data is ready or not.
My code is already written like this. I just need a quick solution for now. Hope it's clear.